# liquid flowing through tiny holes super slowly

Tags: fluid-dynamics, time

How could I make a liquid in a container to flow out of several tiny holes super slowly, let's say that the whole container would empty in a month duration. Is it possible? does it only depend of liquid viscosity?

What i'm trying to do is to measure time in relation to the amount left in the container. My time is 30 days for example.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but you might be interested the [pitch drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_drop_experiment).

Comment: What about just a *really* small pin hole?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the [Hagen–Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) for laminar flow through a regular pipe:

[image: Laminar flow.]

$$\Delta p=\frac{8\mu LQ}{\pi R^4}\tag{1}$$

where:

$\Delta p$ is the pressure difference between the two ends,

$L$ is the length of pipe,

$\mu$ is the dynamic viscosity,

$Q$ is the volumetric flow rate,

$R$ is the pipe radius.

With the layout pictured,

$$\Delta p=\rho g H$$

where $\rho$ is the density of the liquid.

With $(1)$ we get:

$$\boxed{Q=\frac{\pi \rho g H R^4}{8 \mu L}}\tag{2}$$

Comment: According to the equation mentioned in the answer does positive pressure difference in del p indicate the liquid WILL flow from the reservoir through and out of the pipe and negative del p indicate flow will not occur?

Comment: Basically yes. Ta.